# If $\sin^8\theta+\cos^8\theta=\frac{17}{32}$, find the value of $\theta$ using de Moivre's theorem.

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

If
$$\sin^8\theta+\cos^8\theta=\frac{17}{32}$$
find the value of $\theta$ using  de Moivre's theorem. I tried a lot exapanding using Binomial theorem and taking real part and equating it given value.

Comment: Have you tried adapting the methods in the answers to your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2910845/if-sin8x-cos8x-48-128-then-find-the-value-of-x)?

Comment: $$8\cdot17=(e^{ix}-e^{ix})^8+(e^{ix}+e^{ix})^8$$

$$\implies68=(e^{i4x})^2+\binom82e^{i4x}+\binom84$$

Comment: I have tried using previous method suggested to me but I my question paper asked me to solve using De-moviere's theorem.

Comment: Not able to understand

Comment: Fortunately, mathematics is a free science, the obligation to use some result to solve some problem is in best case tolerated if there is an "obvious use". In this case i do not see the (didactical or other) sense of this constraint, if the problem poser does not subscribe to freedom and still insists, use maybe de Moivre's theorem to show $1=e^{it}e^{-it}=(\cos t+i\sin t)(\cos t-i\sin t)=\cos^2t + i\sin^2 t$, then let us forget about it and show that the solutions are of the shape $\theta=k\pi/8$ with an odd integer $k$ by doing computations as wanted.

Comment: @dan_fulea No and yes- if we for instance have "Solve this with(out) the L'Hôpital's rule"- we have to solve it like is written. But if like here we have not even an idea if this problem can be solved by using de Moivre's theorem- we suggest other solutions. I am also wondering from where Priyanka Kumari have this kind of equations  (beside private)

Comment: @Krzysztof Myśliwiec In case of "Solve this using l'Hôspital" - as i was tortured in the school - i can still show mot-a-mot that $x/x\to 1$ by using l'Hôspital then implicitly or explicitly use the factor $1$ in the limit i have to compute. The author of the problem will have to make contortions in the problem request to avoid this solution. All this discussion about constraints is not even part of didactics of mathematics. In my subjective opinion, also not part of mathematics, people imposing constraints of such kind also act outside the mathematical spirit.

Comment: @dan_fulea  ( l'Hôspital was not the best instance) In short- you are right: there are moustly different (and easier or faster) ways to solve a problem. Unless it is a challenge for example (like this one)

Comment: @priyanka kumari I hope you have noticed that someone has provided a full answer to your question, using De Moivre's Theorem as you requested.

Answer (score 3):

De Moivre's Theorem: $e^{ix} = cos(x) + i*sin(x)$.

From this famous equation follow the well-known expressions for the cosine: $ cos(x) = (e^{ix}+e^{-ix})/2$ and the sine: $sin(x) = (e^{ix} -e^{-ix})/(2i)$.

We seek the solutions to the equation $sin^8(x) + cos^8(x) = 17/32$. Substitute the cosine and sine expressions. After some calculation we obtain: $e^{8ix} + 28*e^{4ix} + 70 + 28*e^{-4ix} + e^{-8ix} = 68$.

Now use the cosine formula to rewrite this result in terms of $cos(4x)$ and $cos^2(4x)$:

$cos(4x)*[cos(4x) + 14] = 0$

The second term is positive for all values of $x$. Hence we must solve $cos(4x) = 0$. The result is: $x = (1 + 2k) \pi/8$ where $k = 0, 1, 2,3 ….$ With a pocket calculator you can check numerically that this result is correct.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

According to the formula
\begin{align*}
\sin(2\theta) = 2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)
\end{align*}

We can rewrite the given expresion as

\begin{align*}
\sin^{8}(\theta) + \cos^{8}(\theta) & = [\sin^{4}(\theta) + \cos^{4}(\theta)]^{2} - 2\sin^{4}(\theta)\cos^{4}(\theta)\\
& = [(\sin^{2}(\theta)+\cos^{2}(\theta))^{2} - 2\sin^{2}(\theta)\cos^{2}(\theta)]^{2} - 2\sin^{4}(\theta)\cos^{4}(\theta)\\
& = [1 - 2\sin^{2}(\theta)\cos^{2}(\theta)]^{2} - 2\sin^{4}(\theta)\cos^{4}(\theta)\\
& = \left[1 - \frac{\sin^{2}(2\theta)}{2}\right]^{2} - \frac{\sin^{4}(2\theta)}{8} = 1 -\sin^{2}(2\theta) + \frac{\sin^{4}(2\theta)}{8} = \frac{17}{32}
\end{align*}

Therefore, if we make the substitution $y = \sin(2\theta)$, the given problem is equivalent to
\begin{align*}
& 4y^{4} - 32y^{2} + 15 = 0 \Longleftrightarrow 4(y^{4} - 8y^{2}) + 15 = 0 \Longleftrightarrow 4(y^{4} - 8y^{2} + 16) - 49 = 0 \Longleftrightarrow\\
& 4(y^{2}-4)^{2} = 49 \Longleftrightarrow y^{2} - 4 = \pm\frac{7}{2} \Longleftrightarrow y^{2} = 4\pm\frac{7}{2} \Longleftrightarrow y = \pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} = \pm\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)
\end{align*}

Can you proceed from here?

**EDIT**

According to the Newton's binomial theorem as well as the De Moivre's formula, we have
\begin{align*}
\cos(8\theta) + i\sin(8\theta) = [\cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta)]^{8} = \sum_{k=0}^{8}\binom{8}{k}[\cos(\theta)]^{k}[i\sin(\theta)]^{8-k}
\end{align*}
As a consequence, you can obtain the value of the expression $\sin^{8}(\theta) + \cos^{8}(\theta)$ in terms of sines and cosines and solve the 
corresponding equation.

Comment: Yes  thanks for your answer even I tried this in my paper but I was asked to solve using De-moviere's theorem.

Answer (score 1):

I try to give a solution with the given constraint.
Using de Moivre's formula we will show
$$
\begin{aligned}
\cos^4 t +\sin^4t &=\frac 1{4}\Big[\ \cos 4t+3\ \Big]\ ,
\\
\cos^8 t +\sin^8t &=\frac 1{64}\Big[\ \cos 8t+28\cos 4t +35\ \Big]\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
There is no prize of beauty we can win for the proof, so let us use $c:=\cos t$, $s=\sin t$ as shortcuts for an easy typing. The strategy is to write $\cos 4t$ and $\cos 8t$ in terms of an even polynomial in $c,s$, with no mixed monomials.
Let us get explicit relations:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\cos 4t
&=\text{Real part of }(\cos 4t +i\sin 4t)\\
&=\text{Real part of }(\cos t +i\sin t)^4\quad\text{(de Moivre)}\\
&=c^4-6c^2s^2+s^4\\
&=c^4-3(\underbrace{(c^2+s^2)^2}_{=1}-c^4-s^4)+s^4\\
&=4(c^4+s^4)-3\ ,\\
&\qquad\text{showing the first formula.}\\[2mm]
2c^2s^2
&=(c^2+s^2)^2-c^4-s^4=1-c^4-s^4\ ,\\
4c^4s^4
&=(1-c^4-s^4)^2\\
&=1+c^8+s^8-2c^4-2s^4+2c^4s^4\ ,\qquad\text{ so}\\
2c^4s^4
&=1+c^8+s^8-2c^4-2s^4\ ,\qquad\text{ so}\\[2mm]
\cos 8t
&=\text{Real part of }(\cos 8t +i\sin 8t)\\
&=\text{Real part of }(\cos 4t +i\sin 4t)^2\qquad\text{(de Moivre)}\\
&=\cos^24t-\sin^24t\\
&=2\cos^24t-1\qquad\text{(or going straightforward here...)}\\
&=2(4c^4+4s^4-3)^2
\\
&=\dots
\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
Some further lines are showing the claimed formula for $\cos 8t$. (The term in $c^4s^4$ can be split as above to have only monomials in $c$, or in $s$, or constant ones.)

From the given relation we have to solve the equation in $t$ (instead of $\theta$, which is too hard to type):
$$
\frac {17}{32}
=\frac 1{64}\Big[\ \cos 8t+28\cos 4t +35\ \Big]\ .
$$
Possibly using de Moivre, 
we write again
$\cos 8t = 2\cos^2 4t-1$ and obtain an equation of second degree in $u:=\cos 4t\in[-1,1]$,
$$
\frac {17}{32}
=\frac 1{64}\Big[\ 2u^2+28u +34\ \Big]\ .
$$
Now $17/32$ cancels on both sides, we get $2(u^2+17u)=0$, equivalently (for $|u|\le 1$) $u=0$, i.e. $4t$ is an odd multiple of $\pi/2$, i.e. $t$ is an odd multiple of $\pi/8$.